# dc.js dashboard using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, html2canvas

I'm using dc.js to develop crossfilter charts. Such as rowcharts, barcharts, etc. I'm trying to figure out of how to screen shot the whole page so a user can save and email with all their filters as a gif file. I'm using html2canvas js file to screen shot the whole page. The challenge is that I have to use IE11 and I'm aware its limitation (implement promise.js and polyfill.min.js). As a test, i created a button that will screenshot the page and append the body. The screenshot appears but I dont see any dc charts and the title or text appear different vs my actual page. It seems that it screenshot without any css changes or html2canvas.js file doesn't read SVGs. Im not sure if i'm doing this correctly. Is there a specific way in order to have the charts appear in the screenshot and how to make html2canvas recognize external CSS file or dc.js charts? Is that possible or are there any other js library similar to html2canvas that can capture the whole page with dc.js charts in them?

Please I need help. Deadline is coming and I'm still researching on this.

Comment: Maybe this might help? http://bl.ocks.org/Rokotyan/0556f8facbaf344507cdc45dc3622177

Comment: Thank you for responding! it sort of help but we're handling 20 plus dc charts. HTML2Canvas.js works ok in chrome but no good in IE11. Doesn't display the charts. I did implement polyfill and promise js files but still no luck. Is there library that can work well in IE11 that can develop the charts into canvas?

Comment: I'm still researching but no luck.. I'm switching over to the back end. Html2canvas doesnt work right with IE11... I have posted separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50048981/screenshot-the-whole-web-page-in-java